# Sum the different date total

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following data in my sql table:

```
 Tran_Date          |  Amount 
2013-05-01 20:09:49 | 50.00
2013-05-02 04:09:49 | 50.00
2013-05-02 20:09:49 | 500.00
```

I want sum the amount before next day 5am. The result should as below.

```
Amount 
100.00 
500.00
```

I have try the following code,but the result is wrong:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh, 5, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(dd,1,f.TRAN_DATE)) AS sDate, 
       SUM(Amount) 
FROM TRAN_TABLE 
GROUP BY sDate
```

How do acheive this? thanks

Comment: Please show your attempt...

Comment: I am sorry, I am newbie in sql

Comment: why it was given a minus, it is a reasonable question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract a DATE after subtracting 5 hours and group by that:

```
SELECT
    CAST(DATEADD(hour, -5, TRAN_DATE) AS DATE) AS sDate,
    SUM(Amount)
FROM TRAN_TABLE
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(hour, -5, TRAN_DATE) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Looks to be essentially the same as the 2nd part of Richard's answer except you have introduced an error in that is not valid to reference a column alias in a `GROUP BY` in SQL Server.

Comment: Nor (thankfully) does SQL Server support `GROUP BY` column ordinal.

Comment: @MartinSmith I was wondering about the alias in group - fixed now. I knew SQL Server was backward, but I keep forgetting just how far (I never use it btw). I looked at richards, but didn't understand the `[date]=` whacky syntax, so I used standard sql syntax. I didn't notice the rest - I see it is basically the same though (I didn't "copy").

Comment: @MartinSmith What's wrong with group by ordinal? I find it very handy and very clear and have used it for 30 years and never had a problem

Comment: Same as [order by ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal) IMO. BTW not allowing aliases in `GROUP BY` makes perfect sense as a syntax rule as the `SELECT` defining the alias is logically evaluated after the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,your answer is working well too. I more prefer use your answer because is short and simple.

Answer (score 4):

For any SQL Server version

```
select [Date]=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,DATEADD(HOUR,-5,Tran_Date)),0),
       Total=SUM(Amount)
from tbl
group by DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,DATEADD(HOUR,-5,Tran_Date)),0)
order by [Date];
```

For SQL Server 2008+, you can use the DATE data type

```
select [Date]=CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-5,Tran_Date) as date),
       Total=SUM(Amount)
from tbl
group by CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-5,Tran_Date) as date)
order by [Date];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,even I cannot use your answer, But you give me an idea how to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use the answer?

Comment: Ops...I thought the format is incorrect. But after I try the code is working very well.Thank you very much.